# Finding and logging dynamic text that needs to be translated in django

Tags: django, translation

When django begins translating the page, I would like to find the texts that were marked for translation, but django did not find the msgid for the same in the po/mo file

If I can find it, I would then log it for further processing

Example,

```
message_to_be_translated = _("Hello")
this_message_is_marked_but_wont_be_translated = _(some_variable_name_whose_value_we_dont_know_now)
```

I would like to log the value of "some_variable_name_whose_value_we_dont_know_now" during run time to a file or something.

The reason we wont know the value before hand is

1. it could be from a third party api
2. it could come from a user request

Edit

Where (in which method) does django look for the msgid in the translation file and say that

1. this string has translation id, so let me translate this one
2. this key doesn't have translation id (msgid) set, so let me ignore it.

I want to find the second one to be precise.